# How to access global variable value in multiple template tags

Tags: xslt

I have created a global variable and its been used in two templates I am able to access i first template, not able to get the value in second template . Below are my workings

```
 <xsl:variable name="currentValue"></xsl:variable> //global variable declaration

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="unique-accounts" select="/*/*/*/accountId/text()generate-id()=generate-id(key('account-by-id', .)[1])]"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="$unique-accounts">
      <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="current()"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue"/> //here value is printing
       <xsl:apply-templates select="//secondTemplate"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template> //close od first template

<xsl:template match="secondTemplate"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue"/>  //here value is not printing
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I follow the logic of your code correctly (which is not at all certain), you have declared a global variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentValue"></xsl:variable>
```

i.e. as empty. You are then calling this global variable inside your *second* template:

```
<xsl:template match="secondTemplate"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and getting an empty result - which is exactly what you should expect.

Within your *first* template, the declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="current()"/>
```

overrides the global variable declaration **for the scope of the template** (more precisely, for the following siblings of the declaration and their descendants - but since the declaration is the first thing you do in the template, it comes down to the same thing).

In more technical terms, the binding established within the template **shadows** the binding established by the top-level `xsl:variable` element:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dt-shadows

Comment: is there any work out  to store value to global variable from inside  a template..here in my case store from first template..so that it can be used or consumed in second template

Comment: You can send it as a *parameter* when you call/apply the other template.

Comment: I understand passing a variable as a parameter. But, what if you want this global value several nodes deep? I have an idea about a new feature in my own program and it would loop a Linked in list of names and for each name build the same schedule, but highlight that name wherever it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in XSLT are named values, they are not memory locations in which you can place different values at different times. That's a fundamental difference between declarative and procedural programming.

If you would like to explain the problem you are trying to solve (that is, the input and output of the transformation) then I'm sure we can explain how to write it in XSLT. Reverse-engineering the requirement from a completely wrong approach to the solution isn't possible.