# Do I have to cascade my variable down into each template

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have seen a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407485/how-to-access-global-variable-value-in-multiple-template-tags/28407918#comment85824642_28407918) but I just need to be clear on this.

This is a flow chart of my XML data file:

[image: Flowchart]

Here is a bit of background:

- I have a XML data file with a list of `Name` values inside `HighlightNames` (marked in Orange).
- In the XSL script we import the above XML file and loop the names.
- For each name we create a schedule and want to highlight that name wheverever it is used (marked in Green).

Now, I know that I can assign `HighlightNames\Name` to a variable, eg: `NameToCheck` and then pass it as a `param` into the various templates. But this would be alot of cascading. Eg:

```
HighlightNames\Name
    MeetingWorkBook\Meeting
        TFGW
           TFGWItem
               Name - does it match?
```

So in the above situation we have to cascade the value down 5 times.

Is that correct? There is no way to assign the `NameToCheck` variable at the `HighlightNames\Name` iteration and this be available without the need of cascading?

Thanks for the clarification.

## Clarification

1. I have **XML File A**, that contains the names to highlight.
2. I have **XML File B**, that contains all the schedule data for the month.
3. I have **XSL File C**, this is primarily linked to **File B**.
4. In the top of **File C** we import **File A** and *loop the names*.

I thought I explained the concept with the flow chart. But I never referred to multiple XSL files.

The goal here is to create the schedule for each name, and personalise it by highlighting any where his name is used.

So:

```
Import names XML as varNames
For each name in varNames
    Set varNameToHighlight as name
    For each MeetingWorkbook\Meeting
         Param varNameToHighlight
    End for
End for
```

From what I can tell I have to cascade the name down.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your flow diagram is pretty much definitive in this situation. There are no shortcuts in your diagram. So yes, you have to take 5 steps to reach the destination.

Comment: So with XML 1 there is no real GLOBAL variable that is visible everywhere else. It must be passed down.

Comment: How do you think a global variable could be declared in XSLT(-1.0)? There _are_ different XSLT files! There is _no_ global definition file. At least not according to your diagram.

Comment: No. I have one XSL File. It links in one XML as a reference (the one with list of names) and the main XML that is tied in with XSL (the schedule data). So, I only have one XSL script.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the whole question situation seems unclear to me - so I'm out.

Comment: My schedule content varies each month. When I am looping the names, say Andrew, then, when I am about to display any of those assigned I have to test them against Andrew. If they match, highlight the table cell.

Comment: I see from here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_variable.asp that I will have to pass the variable down since I can’t declare it as a top level element. Only then can it be global and used elsewhere in the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches commonly used.

(a) when processing a node at level 5 in the tree, you can use the ancestor axis to find information about nodes at higher levels. This is fine provided recomputing the "variable" you actually want from the node at this level is not too much work.

(b) in XSLT 2.0+, you can pass tunnel parameters to called templates. Tunnel parameters are passed down through multiple levels of template calling, which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

You've tagged the question XSLT 1.0, but I think you need to look at what is holding you back from moving forward to a more modern version of the language.

Comment: The context is holding me back. My application uses the parsing natively working with the HtmlView control. So I am tied into version 1. Else I assume I would have to also supply an additional parser if indeed it can be used. All my stuff is for XSL and xml to make html in the web browser control.

Comment: If you're running XSLT in the browser, consider Saxon-JS.

Comment: I will look into it as a possibility. But i see it is a purchased product and my applications are free. But I will check at a convenient point in time.